# Proper indendation with backslash line continuations in python-mode.el

Tags: python, emacs, multiline, python-mode

I like to use python-mode.el and (gnu) emacs for editing my python files.  If I use parentheses for multiline continuations, indentation works as I expect.  For example,

```
foo_long_long_long_long = (
    bar_long_long_long_long[
        (x_long_long_long_long == X) &
        (y_long_long_long_long == Y)])
```

is just the way I like it.

On the other hand, if I use a backslash for continuations, a single indentation is created and all subsequent lines stop using the extra indentation logic.  Below the third and fourth lines fail to have any extra indentation

```
foo_long_long_long_long = \
    bar_long_long_long_long[
    (x_long_long_long_long == X) &
    (y_long_long_long_long == Y)]
```

Does anyone know how to fix python-mode.el (5.1.0) so that backslash continuations indent the same as parenthesis continuations?

---

**EDIT:** Although I'm happy to just use parens all day long (python is after all, rather lisp like...), I collaborate with others who use backslash continuations.  Emacs messes up the indentation when I press TAB, which I often do as a reflex.  It'd be nice to be able to edit their files and have emacs keep all its indentation smarts when working with backslash line continuations.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use blackslash continuations.

Comment: For my own code, that's what I've done.  This unfortunately is problematic when I work on files written by collaborators who prefer backslash continuations that work fine in their non-emacs editors.  When I edit their files, it's easy for me to mess up the indentation with emacs (not in a semantic way, but in an aesthetically unpleasing way).

Answer (score 0):

This got Bug lp:629916,  fixed in https://launchpad.net/python-mode